# How do I resolve this CORs issue? Rails 6, ruby-saml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saml, onelogin

I am trying to follow the ruby-saml example code for doing the outbound redirect and am hitting a CORs exception.

The code in question is:
`request = OneLogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new redirect_to(request.create(saml_settings))`

When I try to call this via axios, I get an OPTIONS preflight which rejects me with a 302 and

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

So far, I have tried rack-cors, rails-reverse-proxy and a number of other things but I cannot get past this block.

Does anyone have some good instructions on how to fix this? Why is the redirect not being handled as a simple request? i.e. Why am I getting the OPTIONS preflight? Can I somehow make this a simple request?

Someone was saying that I will need to proxy through something like nginx but that seems overkill this.

rails 6, react if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are experiencing is not related to SAML.

This is related to the fact that you are executing a redirection to a website which hostname mismatch the rails server hostname and the headers that are added on the request.

CORS explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

You need to review your rack-cors settings as well as review if your Apache/Nginx configuration is configured properly.
https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: OK I'm a little confused here then. (a gross understatement). When you say 'your Apache/Nginx configuration', is this for the server I am doing the pre-flight to? i.e. Is this to the onelogin.com server? Wouldn't OneLogin have that configured correctly for CORS?

Comment: Your client (axios) is executing a call to an endpoint (your server) which executes the redirection.  The browser sends a CORS preflight OPTIONS request, and the server’s responding with a 3xx redirect (to be redirected to OneLogin endpoint), and this is not allowed. The issue happens between your client axios and your own server.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will look into the axios/server setup.

Comment: I have reconfigured the web service to use an nginx reverse proxy but I am still getting the same CORS block. Any suggestions would be welcome at this point.

Comment: At the javascript level, why don't you instead of executing an Ajax call to the SAML Login endpoint, simply execute a redirection to the endpoint with:
windows.location.href = "https://example.com/saml/login"  ?

Comment: Thanks. That's what I eventually ended up doing.